# Implementing Login process for my application in iphone and the best ways to encrypt the password and send to the server

Tags: ios

I am implementing a login process for my app, for that I have created a login screen and a sign-in button. So if the user is not signed in I have a register button which opens another form so that the user can register himself, after which I have provided a *Done* button which when clicked will send the information to the server and sends an authentication code to the users email address that the user entered in the iPhone app. Then the user will be registered.

So now I want to know what are the best ways to send the username and password to the server once the user is logged in? How is it possible to save the user name and password so that when at later time when the user opens an application he should not be allowed to login again?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for secure transmission of the credentials is to use Https. On successful authentication you'll receive a "cookie" that you can store locally in the user defaults. That cookie will typically expire. So, on subsequent logins, you can check that the cookie hasn't expired, and continue to use it for your server communication.

If the cookie does expire, then you prompt the user to login again, thereby receiving a new cookie from the server.

Storing any user credentials on the device is a big no no. The only way you can do it is to store a hash of the password. You would still need to check a hash of the entered password with the stored hash to check they are equal. It doesn't really give you anything other than a local - no server required - authentication.

Of course don't forget that without having to login again, the app will be vulnerable. Someone else could use the app and the owner's server session would still be active.